# how to add json animation file to app.json in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-splash-screen, expo-splash-screen

since expo doesn't support gif images as splashscreen, i am trying to use gif as json a file.
Is it possible to use json file in app.json.
If yes, how?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place json file in your project and use it by importing from the relative path.

```
import animation from './animation.json';//if the json file exists in the same folder
```

In the case your project is typescript based you should add "resolveJsonModule": true into "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json file.

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  //...
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  //...
 }
}
```

- There would be right answer if you are only serious to show a git file as Splash
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403026/6602400

Comment: since expo uses app.json file for splash screen, how can i import json file in app.json, i tried replacing existing png image with json file and applied your changes, still it is giving blank white screen in place of splash screen